# Need an advice on Hammer.js to swipe automatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, hammer.js

I'm looking for an example of how to an automatic swipe using Hammer.js.

If anyone has done it, please advice me how to approach the problem.

Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should look into `hammertime.trigger` method. See a small example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/qJEne/2/).

Read more [here](https://github.com/EightMedia/hammer.js/wiki/Instance-methods#hammertimetriggergesture-eventdata)